# Swift - could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I got this error message when trying to load UICollectionView.

> 2015-07-23 16:16:09.754 XXXXX[24780:465607] Terminating app due to
> uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could
> not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
> identifier CollectionViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the
> identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>
> First throw call stack:

My code

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "category")

        return cell

    }
```

I already declared `CollectionViewCell` in storyboard inspector but the error message still occur.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you are creating your Cell nibs separately and not inside your `UICollectionView`. If yes, you need to register the nib file with the `UICollectionView` first. using UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell"];

Answer (score 12):

After taking a look at your exception:

> 2015-07-23 16:16:09.754 XXXXX[24780:465607] * Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could
>   not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier CollectionViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' * First throw
>   call stack:

last part is most important:

> must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Which means that your collection view doesn't have registered your custom cell. To resolve this add following in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "UICollectionElementKindCell", bundle:nil)
self.collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

Comment: Thank you. my problem was that I was not registering my Nib and instead registering the class with:   self.collectionView!.registerClass(customCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")                          Your code works however.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 3:

```
collectionView.register(YourCustomCellClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad() put in this code

```
collectionView.registerClass(YourCustomCellClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```