# Swift - could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jtapplecalendar

I got this error message when trying to load my project

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CustomCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

My code is:

```
extension ViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate, JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {
    func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")!
        let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 12 31")!

        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
        return parameters
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
        return cell
    }
}
```

Please help me debug this problem. Thank you.

Edit: I have added the identifier for the cell, but still the error exists.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: did you add CustomCell reuseIdentifier in collectionviewcell in storyboard ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581903/swift-could-not-dequeue-a-view-of-kind-uicollectionelementkindcell-with-ident)

Comment: @NishantBhindi None of those answers worked for me :/

Comment: what is the class of your cell ? have you set class in `identity inspector` ?

Comment: is this resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you haven't registered your xib to `UICollectionView`. If you are using `UICollectionViewCell` from Xib, you must register it first.

```
In viewDidLoad:
```

write it:

```
if let xib = NSNib.init(nibNamed: "TemplateNBgCollectionItem", bundle: nil) {
   self.collectionView.register(xib, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cvItem"))  
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to this. When i tried your suggestion, I get the following error - 

Use of unresolved identifier 'collectionView'

Comment: oh thats because I have taken collectionView as dummy text. what you have to do is this: make an IBOutlet of UICollectionView named collectionView. Then you are good to go

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly I need to do and where i need to put it. Sorry, but this is my first time doing all of this

Comment: Go to that controller on IB. Ctrl + drag to your this controller class. then when it prompts , use name : collectionView

Answer (score 10):

In `viewDidLoad` method:
You must register your custom cell class/xib name with collectionView object.

If you have only class custom class then you register by following way (No xib file)

```
collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

If you have both class as well as xib file then you can register by this way

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

Comment: I used This But I still having problem with line         let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleDayCellView(withReuseIdentifier: "JTCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! JTCustomCell

Answer (score 4):

From the code snippets you pasted, I don't see you register the cell before you want to dequeue/use it. Need to register the cell before use as the error described.

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

For your quick reference, please see below post -
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

---

Edit after screenshot posted

From the screenshot, you are using a custom cell class 'CustomCell', after you set the correct identifier, please make sure setup the correct class name as CustomCell in the identity inspector of right panel. Refer to below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I see your screenshot after you update, just be careful when you connect the IBOutlet, and make sure the name is matched with your xib. or you can re-connect it to double check. Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

1. If you use cell in storyboard not **XIB** then you need to set reuseIDentifier as below[image]
2. If you use separate **XIB** for cell then you need to add this line in `ViewDidLoad`

   collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for this issue. If you have custom class for `collection view` then it should be set in  `identity inspector`. And it must be subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. And you have to instantiate that subclass in your `cellforitem` delegate method with proper `reusable identifier` that must be set in `attribute inspector`. Here in your screen shot, It seems like `Apple calender view` is your collection view. If it is third party library then make sure that it is allowing you to deque your custom cells! and make sure it is subclass of `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

**In My Case**
Im creating a collection View with custom cell with class
[image: CollectionView + Custom Collection Cell + Custom Collection Cell Class]
[image: Reused Identifier]
[image: Custom Collection View Class]

**This Is my Custom CollectionView Class Code**

```
import UIKit
class Auction_CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Productimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bid: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progress: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var day: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hours: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mins: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secs: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblday: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblhours: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblmin: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblsecs: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var MainView: UIView!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Connect all the view from your storyboard to Custom Class by CTRL+Drag and @IBOutlet will be created.

**I Called my custom class like this**

> self.AuctionList = NSArray with NSDictionary Content

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.AuctionList.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let cell : Auction_CollectionCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as? Auction_CollectionCell)!

    cell.lblday.text = "Day"
    cell.lblhours.text = "Hours"
    cell.lblmin.text = "Minutes"
    cell.lblsecs.text = "Secs"

    cell.MainView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.MainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.MainView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.MainView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor


    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
 var width = CGFloat(0)
 var height = CGFloat(0)
 if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
   width = CGFloat((self.view.bounds.size.width / 4.0) - 15)
   height = CGFloat(246.0)
 }else{
   width = CGFloat((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0) - 15)
   height = CGFloat(246.0)
}

   print("Resize Image \(width) \(height)")
   return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if let dic = AuctionList[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
    Product.product_id = "\((dic["product_id"])!)"
    Product.product_image = "\((dic["image"])!)"
    Product.auction_id = "\((dic["auction_id"])!)"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "auctionProductDetails", sender: self)
  }      
}
```

Have fun And Good Luck.
Feel Free to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with mine. and after looking around i realised i had a lower case "p" when it should've been an upper case "P" with the name i used for an identifier.

click on the collectionView cell on the storyboard, open the right panel. Check attributes inspector and collection Reusable View, identifier name, but also check the identity inspector, custom class name.