# Not able to load a collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm loading a `collectionview` in my storyboard. But when I run it, it was not showing up. It was then that I figured out that the delegate and datasource was not set. But when I set the delegate & datasource and run again, the program crashes saying `'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier prdImgscellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

It seems I didn't miss anything..but not able to figure out why the crash is happening..

This is my `cellForItemAt...`

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! productImagesCollectionViewCell

     cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "appLogo.jpg")

     return cell
 }
```

Comment: Are you using custom cell or custom header ?

Comment: I think I'm using a custom cell...what is a custom header btw..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581903/swift-could-not-dequeue-a-view-of-kind-uicollectionelementkindcell-with-ident)

Comment: Make sure there will me not typo with cell identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Set cell identifier in CollectionViewCell in Storyboard as `prdImgscellIdentifier`,

Or may be if it is because you haven't registered your xib to UICollectionView. If you are using UICollectionViewCell from Xib, you must register it first.

In viewDidLoad: 
write it:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "name", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Comment: Have you made custom class for cell? If yes, then assign the same class to cell in Storyboard

Comment: I assume, it is because you haven't registered your xib to UICollectionView. If you are using UICollectionViewCell from Xib, you must register it first.

In viewDidLoad: 
write it:

collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "name", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "prdImgscellIdentifier")

Comment: can you change cell identifier from prdImgscellIdentifier to cell only

Comment: productImagesCollectionViewCell is you custom class name right? And you have set that class for cell in storyboard inside collectionview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157971/discussion-between-baig-and-bws).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register your customCellClass in viewDidLoad...  Please check this previous answer for full details:

[Swift - could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581903/swift-could-not-dequeue-a-view-of-kind-uicollectionelementkindcell-with-ident)

Comment: I'm showing the collectionview directly from the storyboard and I suppose the link u suggested is useful in case we are using the xib...

Comment: From that link, did you try @Mohsen's advice to register the class in `viewDidLoad()`: `collectionView.register(productImagesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "prdImgscellIdentifier")`

Comment: but i'm directly using from storyboard...so will i need to register from nib..?

Comment: what happens when you copy and paste `collectionView.register(productImagesCollectionViewCell.self‌​, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "prdImgscellIdentifier")` within the viewDidLoad() code block in the same .swift file you have the cellForItemAt function? Does it still crash?

Answer (score 0):

have u implemented required datasource?

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your storyboard on storyboard and assign an Identifier in utilities window "cell" like Below in this image

[image]